# Allow more than 24 hours in Time Type field in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm developing a Web App in symfony for an older desktop aplication, I have an entity Flight that has a field called delay. A delay could be for example: 35 hours and 35 minutes. Because is a newer version of an old system I have to keep the interface similar to the older system as much I can. So I need to show this field in the form as hours and minutes. I used TimeType Field and works just fine but not allows submit more than 24 hours. I wonder if there is a solution for this that allow me to render this field as hours and minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [DateIntervalType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/dateinterval.html)

> This field allows the user to select an interval of time. For example,
>   if you want to allow the user to choose how often they receive a
>   status email, they could use this field to choose intervals like every
>   "10 minutes" or "3 days".

Comment: is right is not a problem with doctrine and database is the way the form is rendered, and mantain hours and minutes format, I read about DateIntervalType Field but this is new after Symfony 3.2 and I'm using 3.1. I will have to upgrade and try it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the symfony version in the question. Maybe you can just use it separately or port it in order not to update?